# Хранение cookie в браузерах

Tags: php, cookie

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с тем что браузеры - Safari, Firefox, ЯндексБраузер, очень не долго хранят куки.
С чем это связанно? Chrome к примеру четко хранит, долго по времени как указываю в коде. Все остальные по разному, некоторые теряют кук через пол часа кто то через сутки.

Вот код как я это делаю:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
session_set_cookie_params('3600');
ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", true);
session_start();
ini_set ("display_errors", true);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
```

....
....

Сохраняю куки:

```
setcookie ("param1", $value1, time() + (3600*24*365), "/", "scroll");               
setcookie ("param2", $value2, time() + (3600*24*365), "/", "scroll");
```

Вроде бы все правильно делаю.

Спасибо большое!

PS.

Теперь все на оборот, сохраняеться в фаерфоксе, сафари, но напрочь отказывается сохранять куки в хроме и Яндекс.Браузере

Вот пример что я делаю (перепробовал разные вариант)

```
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    session_set_cookie_params(3600);
    ini_set ("session.use_trans_sid", '1');
    my_session_start();
    ini_set ("display_errors", '1');
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');


    function my_session_start()
    {
        if (ini_get('session.use_cookies') && isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
            $sessid = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
        } elseif (!ini_get('session.use_only_cookies') && isset($_GET['PHPSESSID'])) {
            $sessid = $_GET['PHPSESSID'];
        } else {
            session_start();
            return false;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{32}$/', $sessid)) {
            return false;
        }
        session_start();
        return true;
    }
```

Дальше сохраняю куки так:

```
$path   = "/";
$domen  = "localhost";
setcookie ("login", $row['email'],  time() + (3600*24*365), $path, $domen);
```

Они просто не появляются в списке куков. А вот сессия норм, сохраняется.

Дальше попробовал убрать $path и $domen, начал сохранять куки. Но вот к примеру сессию не сохраняет в сафаре, яндекс.браузере и фаерфоксе, а в хроме и сессию сохраняет и куки хранит. :(

Comment: Для начала стоит посмотреть какое значение expires на самом деле попадает в браузер (то есть что сам браузер сообщит о полученных куках).

Comment: у вас "scroll" указан в качестве домена. может в этом проблема? вообще-то современные браузеры почти безупречно выполняют стандарты. ато есть разница в том как они реагируют на ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно проверяйте насколько ваши данные соответствуют описанию параметров функций. Например непонятно зачем вы пишете *"3600"* там где ожидается целое значение, *true* там где нужна строка или значение "scroll" в качестве домена.
Описанная вами проблема может быть и не конкретно от этих вещей возникает, но вы вероятно и не весь код привели. Будьте внимательны!

Comment: Я уже и не знаю в чем дело. Испраил. теперь у меня прекрасно пишутся куки в Фаерфокс и Сафари, но напрочь перестали писаться в Яндекс.Браузере и Хроме. Причем сессия сохраняется а куки не пишуться.  Не знаю как тут привести пример. :(

Answer (score -1):

Автор сам же установил параметр

```
session_set_cookie_params('3600');
```

Который явно указывает время жизни кукам в один час.

UPD: Отлично работает во всех браузерах

```
setcookie('my_cookie', 'my_value', strtotime('+365 days'), '/');
```

UPD: Внимательно смотри на свой код (ошибка очевидна).

P.S. Я ждал хотя бы комментария к отрицательному отзыву об ответе :)